# Dragging an image around on top of another one - like a cake design tool?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have no idea where to start with this problem, so I am hoping for some guidance to get the ball rolling, essentially I am trying to have two pictures, one that is underneath, and one that is on top, which I can drag around and position it against the lower image.

Kind of like when you upload a picture to a cake design company, and you can upload a picture, then more it around on the surface?

I wish I had code to show for this, but I keep failing it really badly :(

I have included javascript and jquery tags here because I assume they might be needed, but apologies if they are not!

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#snap-to Code is already written, just implement it. :)

Comment: We don't know what "cake design company" is

Comment: thanks @nevermind - This is exactly what I needed - just a pointer in the right direction!

Comment: also @m02ph3u5 - No need to be a douche. You know exactly what a cake design company does, and you are just trying to be difficult.

Comment: In fact I don't. Do you mean cake PHP? Or are er talking about real cake? Then again, I don't design cakes. Especially not on my pc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#board").mousemove(function(e) {
    $('#pawn').css({
      'top': e.clientY - 20,
      'left': e.clientX - 20
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#pawn {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<img id="board" src="http://files.chesscomfiles.com/images_users/tiny_mce/DENVERHIGH/CHESS%20BOARD%20EMPTY%202.jpg" />


<img id="pawn" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/45/Chess_plt45.svg/50px-Chess_plt45.svg.png" />
```

Comment: I like this. Very simple

Comment: Damn - this is pretty much exactly what I was looking for! Even with the boundaries etc! I have another stack overflow account, and I have been here for years, and I realize my question was worded in a really vague way because I had no idea what I was looking for. That said, nobody has ever answered a question for me so correctly. Thanks!